# Is there a way for the user to specify how many folder levels my script will search?

Tags: bash

im building a small bash script project.My code getting 2 arguments, one path to search and one number that tells me how many folders level i have to analyze.
For Example if the user gives the number 2 my programm it must search all directories within it and all directories within them.

```
#!/bin/bash

function check_dir {
    echo Checking dir : $1
    for f in `ls $1`
    do
        if [ -d $1/$f ]
        then
            dirs_num=$(($dirs_num+1))
            check_dir $1/$f
        else    
            files_num=$(($files_num+1))
            size=`stat -c%s $1/$f`
            echo $1/$f - $size
        fi
    done
}

files_num=0
dirs_num=0
depth=$2
check_dir $1
echo "Found $files_num files and $dirs_num dirs."
```

This is my code so far, im giving the path when i execute it but it gives me result for any folder that it finds.So how can i stop this loop?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [find](/questions/tagged/find).

Quoteth the manpage

> ```
>  -maxdepth levels
>        Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories
>        below  the command line  argu‐ments.  -maxdepth 0  means only apply the
>        tests and actions to the command line arguments.
> ```

With a bit of [find](/questions/tagged/find), GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), and [sort](/questions/tagged/sort), you can do what you want in a *safe manner.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
  BEGIN{ RS="\0" } # Non-portable, requires GNU awk
  $1 != dir{
        print "Checking dir : " $1
        dcnt++
        dir = $1
  }
  {
        print $1$2 " - " $3
        fcnt++
  }
  END{
        print "Found " fcnt " files and " dcnt " dirs."
  }' <(find "$1" -maxdepth "$2" -type f -printf "%h\t%f\t%s\0" | LC_ALL=C sort -z )
```

By *safe I mean each record is NUL terminated and [doesn't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @ΣωτηρηςΙωαννιδης check answer for a safer way to do what you want